# Embed code through macro

Tags: c++, c

I try to embed a code block through the use of macro like this:

```
#define RUN_CODE_SNIPPET(c) do {\
  c\
} while(0);
```

where 'c' is a code block enclosed inside '{ }'

Here is how to use it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RUN_CODE_SNIPPET(c) do {\
  c\
} while(0);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  RUN_CODE_SNIPPET({
    //const char *message   = "World";  
    const char  message[] = {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'};  
    printf("%s\r\n", message);
  });

  return 0;
}
```

You can run it here [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJbZBCnBQ)

But I get compiler error when I use the initializer list format

> ```
> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:13:4: error: macro "RUN_CODE_SNIPPET" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 1
>     });
>     ^
> test.c:9:3: error: ‘RUN_CODE_SNIPPET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
> RUN_CODE_SNIPPET({   
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> test.c:9:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each
> function it appears in
> ```

Seems the compiler is taking each element in the initializer list as the argument to the macro itself. The string initializer works fine.

What is wrong here?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: What's wrong?  You can't pass arbitrary C code as a single argument to a macro.  Maybe you should be using variable arguments: `#define RUN_CODE_SNIPPET(...) do {\
  __VA_ARGS__ \
} while(0);`

Comment: the commas in `'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'` are seen as argument delimiters. I'm afraid you cannot do that, but even without that it won't work

Comment: Look at all of those commas in `{'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'};`... all of those *argument separating commas*... I suggest `const char message[] = "world";`...

Comment: Thanks all!. Using the {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'} is just an example here. I had the macro working in multiple cases for a couple weeks until it starts "break" when I use intializer list for an object. (right...I was using C++ instead of C in my original code).

Answer (score 5):

The commas in what you pass inside the parentheses are interpreted as macro argument separators and the macro is expecting just one argument.

There are two ways around the problem:

1. parenthesize the commas-containing argument, i.e., pass `(a,b,c)` instead of `a,b,c` (not applicable in your case because your argument is not an expression)
2. use variadic macro arguments (`...` -> `__VA_ARGS__`)

In other words:

```
#define RUN_CODE_SNIPPET(...) do { __VA_ARGS__; }while(0)
```

will work (including the semicolon at the end of the macro is not advisable -- for a function-like macro, you should generally be able to do `if(X) MACRO(something); else {}` and the semicolon would mess that up).

Comment: Good point on the trailing semicolon on the macro definition.  I missed that when I made my comment.